# How to print a TabPage which has TextBoxes and graphs using a button?

Tags: vb.net

I have a TabPage including TextBoxes and graph, how can I either export all the items into a PDF file or print the entire page? thanks so much.

```
Print1.Document = PrintDoc1
If (Print1.ShowDialog() = DialogResults.Ok) Then
    PrintDoc1.Print()
End If
```

' Do not know how to refer to the page1 to print? tnx.

Comment: When you say "print the page" is this a winforms page (form)?  Also, your title says C#, but your code and tag are VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry, that is VB, and trying to print one of the tabpages from the winforms, thanks.

Comment: This isn't built in anymore. VB6 forms had a simple Print() option, but with .Net you have to re-draw everything yourself to the PrintDocument object during it's Print_Page event. That means rendering your own graph, too.

Comment: As @Joel said, if you want to print part of the form (e.g., a TabPage), you'll need to do it yourself using the `DrawToBitmap` method and the `PrintDocument` class. However, if you're okay with printing the whole form _(all its visible contents)_, [there's an easy way to do so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/printing/how-to-print-a-form-by-using-the-printform-component).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Control.DrawToBitMap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. It works because forms also inherit from the base Control type. Then you can draw the bitmap to the `PrintDocument` object. To do that, you have to [handle the PrintPage event.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=netframework-4.7.2)